# Problem in values of registers

Tags: architecture, mips, cpu-architecture

I was trying to solve this homework assignment but was unable to come up with a solution. Below is the problem,

> Translate this code into MIPS machine

```
once_more:
    lw $5, 48($6)
    sub $5, $5, $2
    bne $5, $0, once_more
```

Now the problem I am facing is that I have no idea what should be the value of the registers in this problem (I only studied `$t0-$t7`(8-15) and `$s0-$s7` (16-23) values). Can anyone please help me with the values of these registers?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this document](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~ghosh/1-27-09.pdf), I think the registers being referenced are as follows:

- `$5` -> `$a1`
- `$6` -> `$a2`
- `$2` -> `$v0`

`$0` is the `$zero` register.

`$a-` registers hold arguments, while `$v1` registers hold results. One of the purposes of these registers is for use by syscalls; for example, the `print_int` syscall will print the value in `$a0` as an integer.

Translating these to machine code will mean that you need to convert the assembly statement into the binary machine equivalent. The [MIPS Green Card](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf) will help you here. Look at the "Basic Instruction Formats" section for an explanation of how the instructions are laid out in binary.